# Post-send email in JourneyBuilder

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting, ampscript, journeybuilder

Is there a way to see the actual email sent to a contact that was in a journey?

My tests showed that the email was working and the ampscript populating correctly, but I'd like to actually verify what John Doe received yesterday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way to check out the very email sent as Marketing Cloud doesn't store them (or at least doesn't make them available to the customer), but you can do check what has been sent using a workaround:

**Check if the subscriber received the mail:**

1. Go to *Email Studio -> Tracking -> Sends -> Journey Builder Sends*
2. Select your Journey and version
3. Click on the triggered email (send activity) you want to see.
4. Filter for the date range you like to check
5. Click on the number next to "Total sent"
6. Find the subscriber you want to check (**Now we know the subscriber received the mail)
7. Copy the subscriberkey

**Check out how the personalized email looked like:**

1. Go to *Email Studio -> Content*
2. Navigate to the desired email
3. Click the arrow to the right of the email and select "Preview and Test"
4. Go to "Subscriber Preview and Attributes"
5. Click on the folder-icon
6. Select the data extension of the triggered send (created by journey builder for the email activity)
7. Search for the subscriber key and click on the subscriber
8. Click on the "Select"-button

Comment: When I do this - everything looks great and the links work.  

However, when I look at the Click Activity data in the Send Report.  I get a link that they clicked that looks like this (which is what concerns me):  
[https://teamlocker.squadlocker.com/?cm_ven=ExactTarget&cm_cat=SE_SquadLockerTeamStore_Parent_Email1_backlog&cm_pla=All+Subscribers&cm_ite=https%3a%2f%2fteamlocker.squadlocker.com%2f%23%2flockers%2f%%SL_Store_Id%%%2f&cm_lm=michellehrlw@yahoo.com&cm_ainfo=&&&&%%__AdditionalEmailAttribute4%%&%%__AdditionalEmailAttribute5%%#/lockers/52226/]  
@markus

Comment: Do you have any doubt this hasn't worked for the subscriber? As unfortunately you won't get nearer to the actual sent mail than using the email of the activity, the data extension containing the subscriber data that is used in the journey and the data of the actual subscriber.

Comment: These are parameters added to every link if the tracking feature is enabled for the send. First the user is redirected to click.yourmaildomain.tld with an id attached and then redirected to the actual url of the link with added tracking parameters from marketing cloud. these additionalparameters can be configured in the email (if activated in your account). Just the last part seems a bit strange. Maybe you want to share the code creating the link, so I can review it?

Comment: I have a lot of doubts about Marketing Cloud, as a whole :)  

I'm adding myself as a contact into every journey until I am confident.  This is probably the very best option while warming up an IP to assure that ampscript & links are all active.

Comment: Here is the URL I used:  
'https://teamlocker.squadlocker.com/#/lockers/%%SL_Store_Id%%'  

Here's the one I think I should be using:  
`%%[
     SET @link = "https://teamlocker.squadlocker.com/#/lockers/"
     SET @Store_Id = "%%SL_Store_Id%%"
     SET @URL = Concat(@link, @Store_Id)
]%%
     %%=v(@URL)=%%`

Comment: Yes, you should use concat and in addition I suggest using AttributeValue to retrieve the personalization String, so there is no problem if it is empty. Furthermore to ensure the links work correctly use RedirectTo in your href-attribute: `<a href="%%=RedirectTo(Concat('teamlocker.squadlocker.com/#/lockers/', AttributeValue('SL_Store_Id')))=%%">Linktext</a>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60845/discussion-between-tom-callahan-and-markus-slabina).